# React Native call Touchable programatically

Tags: reactjs, react-native, button, touchableopacity

I need to simulate button press in react

At the top of the stateless functional component:

```
const buttonRef = React.useRef ()
```

Inside the render method:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  style={dayStyles[0]}
  ref={buttonRef}
  onPress={() => toggleDay(0, false, startDate, endDate)}
>
```

In a different function:

```
buttonRef._touchable.handlePress ()
```

This is the code I have right now and it doesn't work. I'm trying to simulate the button press from inside a different method. I know I could just call the toggleDay function from a different function but the reason this does not work is because useState changes are not reflected immediately. This is why I need to simulate a button press, which will refresh the state variables on press.